# How to make Minimax function run for multiple piles

Tags: python, minimax

Here is my brief: 'Nimsticks is a turn-taking zero-sum game for two players. The game state consists of one or more piles of sticks. On their turn, a player may take 1, 2 or 3 sticks from any one pile. The player who takes the last stick is the loser of the game.

The problem is my code works fine when there is only one pile ([4], 1) but if I run it with multiple piles ([2, 3], 1) the if statements maxValue < v and minValue > v aren’t triggered (which they always should be due to inf) and are causing an error. Please help!

```
import copy
import math
 
def minimax_value(state):
    if (state[0] == []):
        return(result(state))
    else:
        if (state[1] == 1):
            v, path = (max_value(state))
        else:
            v, path = (min_value(state))
    optimalPath = path
    optimalPath.append(state)
    optimalPath.reverse()
    print('Example play: ' + str(optimalPath))
    return str(v)
 
def terminal(state):
    if (state[0] == []):
        return True
    else:
        return False
 
def utility(state):
    if (state[1] == 1):
        return(1, [])
    else:
        return(-1, [])
 
def max_value(state):
    if terminal(state):
        return(utility(state))
    else:
        v = -1 * math.inf
        for c in next_states(state):
            minValue, minPath = min_value(c)
            if (minValue > v):
                v = minValue
                bestPath = minPath.copy()
                bestSucc = c
        bestPath.append(bestSucc)
        return(v, bestPath)
 
def min_value(state):
    if terminal(state):
        return(utility(state))
    else:
        v = 1 * math.inf
        for c in next_states(state):
           maxValue, maxPath = max_value(c)
           if (maxValue < v):
               v = maxValue
               bestPath = maxPath.copy()
               bestSucc = c
        bestPath.append(bestSucc)
        return(v, bestPath)
 
def next_states(state):
   
    player = state[1]
    piles = copy.deepcopy(state[0])
    pilesSave = copy.deepcopy(piles)
    temp = []
    newList = []
 
    for x in range(0, len(piles)):
        for y in range(1, 4):
            piles[x] = piles[x] - y
            if (piles[x] >= 0):
                temp = copy.deepcopy(piles)
                if (piles[x] == 0):
                    del temp[x]
                    newList.append(temp)
                    break
                newList.append(temp)
            piles[x] = pilesSave[x]
    newList2 = []
    for item in newList:
        if (player == 1):
            toAdd = (item, 2)
        else:
            toAdd = (item, 1)
        newList2.append(toAdd)
       
    return(newList2)
 
 
print(minimax_value(([2, 3], 1)))
```

Comment: when i copy & paste this code i get `local variable 'bestPath' referenced before assignment` thrown on line 41 which is this line `bestPath.append(bestSucc)`.

Comment: i also see a linting error online 6: which would presumably throw an error as `result` is not defined.